# CupertinoTabBar blocks current Tab bottom part how to avoid this or is it a default behavior

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I change my `BottomNavigatorBar` to `CupertinoTabBar` and it does not compress the current `Tab`,

in other words I wouldn't be able to show some information which is at the bottom part of that current tab because `CupertinoTabBar` blocks it.

I don't know it is an default behavior for `Cupertino` style but I need to solve it.  I try to wrap my pages with `CupertinoTabView` and/or `CupertinoPageScaffold`, both does not work.

Do you have any advice ?

[image]
[image]

here is my related code :

```
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(currentIndex: 2, items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.explore), title: Text('Explore')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.card_travel), title: Text('Adventure')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text('Search')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.map), title: Text('Create Tour')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile')),
      ]),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) => ExplorePage(),
            );
            break;
          case 1:
            return AdventurePage();
            break;
          case 2:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) => SearchTourPage(),
            );
            break;
          case 3:
            return BasicRouteInfoForm();
            break;
          case 4:
            return ProfilePage();
            break;
          default:
            return SearchTourPage();
        }
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 7):

Just provide `backgroundColor` which is not translucent, i.e. has opacity of 1.0 (opacity is less than 1.0 by default):

```
return CupertinoTabScaffold(
  tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
    backgroundColor: CupertinoTheme.of(context).barBackgroundColor.withOpacity(1.0),
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
 // ...
```

It implements the same logic as the [`CupertinoNavigationBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageScaffold/navigationBar.html):

> If translucent, the main content may slide behind it. Otherwise, the
>   main content's top margin will be offset by its height.

The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html) is not very clear about this, probably because this is the common logic for Cupertino navigation widgets (`CupertinoTabBar` and `CupertinoNavigationBar` at least) and is considered intuitive.

Looks like [this method](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bf8e2c1449423a6f2e00919f8ee329f742390cd9/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/bottom_tab_bar.dart#L134-L140) affects positioning of the main content and the tab bar:

```
/// Indicates whether the tab bar is fully opaque or can have contents behind
/// it show through it.
bool opaque(BuildContext context) {
  final Color backgroundColor =
      this.backgroundColor ?? CupertinoTheme.of(context).barBackgroundColor;
  return CupertinoDynamicColor.resolve(backgroundColor, context).alpha == 0xFF;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bug but, just add a value to the prop backgroundColor of CupertinoTabBar:

tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the `height` of your contents or add `SizedBox` under your content.

Comment: I thought I could solve it like that but it's not a good solution for this problem, I have to do this for every page.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

main()=>runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyApp> {
  int currentTabIndex = 0;

  onTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentTabIndex = index;
    });
  }

  List<Widget> tabs = [
    FirstPage(),
    SecondPage(),
    ThirdPage(),
    FourthPage(),
    FifthPage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
      return MaterialApp(
              home: Scaffold(
                              body: CupertinoTabScaffold(
            tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home), title: Text("Home")),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.search), title: Text("Search")),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person), title: Text("User Info")),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add), title: Text("sample Info")),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add_circled), title: Text("sample2 Info"))
            ]),
            tabBuilder: (context, index) {
                switch (index) {
                  case 0:
                    return FirstPage();
                  case 1:
                    return SecondPage();
                  case 2:
                    return ThirdPage();
                  case 3:
                    return FourthPage();
                  case 4:
                    return FifthPage();
                  default:
                    return FirstPage();
                }
            }),
              ),
      );
    
 

  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}

class ThirdPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}

class FourthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}

class FifthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FifthPageState createState() => _FifthPageState();
}

class _FifthPageState extends State<FifthPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}
```

check out this example maybe this can help

Comment: Hello, with your example, how can I go to the subpage without missing the menubar ?